# Query to get record list as per particular column data

Tags: sql, oracle

I want active ids but not those record which have I' as status till next record for that id but if the previous record has status 'A' then it should come but not after the status 'I record'.

INPUT:

| id | start_date | end_date | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000000278 | 8/25/2021 | 8/25/2022 | I |
| 1000000278 | 8/25/2022 | 8/25/2023 | A |
| 1000000284 | 8/20/2021 | 8/25/2022 | A |
| 1000000284 | 8/25/2022 | 8/25/2023 | A |
| 1000000285 | 8/20/2024 | 8/20/2028 | A |
| 1000000285 | 8/21/2028 | 8/20/2030 | I |
| 1000000285 | 8/21/2030 | 8/20/2031 | A |
| 1000000286 | 8/25/2021 | 8/25/2022 | A |

OUTPUT:

| id | start_date | end_date | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000000284 | 8/20/2021 | 8/25/2022 | A |
| 1000000284 | 8/25/2022 | 8/25/2023 | A |
| 1000000285 | 8/20/2024 | 8/20/2028 | A |
| 1000000286 | 8/25/2021 | 8/25/2022 | A |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row processing. To get the rows for each `id` with the earliest status of `A` until the first status `I` row, you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY id
  ORDER BY start_date
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( ^ a_status+ )
  DEFINE a_status AS status = 'A'
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, start_date, end_date, status) AS
SELECT 1000000278, DATE '2021-08-25', DATE '2022-08-25', 'I' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1000000278, DATE '2022-08-25', DATE '2023-08-25', 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1000000284, DATE '2021-08-20', DATE '2022-08-25', 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1000000284, DATE '2022-08-25', DATE '2023-08-25', 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1000000285, DATE '2024-08-20', DATE '2028-08-20', 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1000000285, DATE '2028-08-21', DATE '2030-08-20', 'I' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1000000285, DATE '2030-08-21', DATE '2031-08-20', 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1000000286, DATE '2021-08-25', DATE '2022-08-25', 'A' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | START_DATE | END_DATE | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000000284 | 2021-08-20 00:00:00 | 2022-08-25 00:00:00 | A |
| 1000000284 | 2022-08-25 00:00:00 | 2023-08-25 00:00:00 | A |
| 1000000285 | 2024-08-20 00:00:00 | 2028-08-20 00:00:00 | A |
| 1000000286 | 2021-08-25 00:00:00 | 2022-08-25 00:00:00 | A |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uyM9UVxh)

Comment: I have checked, it is not taking alias with two tables

Select * FROM QC_MASTER.QT_BUP_OFFLINE_INS_DTLS BUP 
  MATCH_RECOGNIZE(PARTITION BY DM_CODE 
  ORDER BY INS_START_DATE, INS_END_DATE 
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH 
  PATTERN(^ ACTIVE_STATUS +) 
  DEFINE ACTIVE_STATUS AS ACTIVE = 'A')
 WHERE UPLOAD_ID = 1
   AND RECORD_STATUS = 'VALID'
   AND RECORD_NO BETWEEN 1 AND 2
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM QC_MASTER.QT_BATCH_UPLOAD_ISSUES BUI
         WHERE BUI.UPLOAD_ID = BUP.UPLOAD_ID
           AND BUI.RECORD_NO = BUP.RECORD_NO);
It is throws error Invalid Identifier for BUP

Comment: please check my above comment

Comment: @AkankshaSrivastava Depending on your requirements, filter first in a sub-query and then apply `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` or else apply the alias to the `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zPHz7Eo0)